# I am having difficulty understanding Generics

Tags: c#, generics, unity-game-engine

I am having some difficulty understanding Generics. I am writing this unity code. and it seems as though just calling rigidbody.velocity is outdated. After some searching I found that they have updated to using `GetComponent<T>`. I understand generics increase reusability, and ease casting. In this case, what is `GetComponent<T>`. Is it a class? When I say `GetComponent<Rigidbody>()` is this the constructor? Why do I even need to call a constructor?

```
public class Mover : MonoBehaviour {

    public float speed;
    private Rigidbody moverRigid;

    // Use this for initialization
    void Start () {
        moverRigid = GetComponent<Rigidbody>();
        moverRigid.velocity = transform.forward * speed;
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update () {

    }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> In this case, what is `GetComponent<T>`. Is it a class?

No, it's not a class, it's a generic method. A generic method is used as any other method but it's declared with parameters. In this case your parameter is `Rigidbody`. To get more information about generic methods, please check [this MSDN article](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/twcad0zb.aspx)

> When I say GetComponent() is this the constructor? Why do I even need to call a constructor?

It's not a constructor, it's just a standard method as `Start` but defined on a base class (notice that Mover inherits from `MonoBehaviour`)

Answer (score 2):

[`GetComponent<Rigidbody>()`](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Component.GetComponent.html) is not a constructor. It is a method on the `MonoBehaviour` class that returns a value that is already cast to type `Rigidbody`.

This is explained in Unity's [documentation](http://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/GenericFunctions.html).

> These are known as generic functions. The significance they have for
>   scripting is that you get to specify the types of parameters and/or
>   the return type when you call the function.

Comment: I don't seem to be returning a value. I'm sorry if that seems dumb. I'm setting moverRigid = to the method???

Comment: @christopher You are setting `moverRigid` to the return value of the call to `GetComponent<Rigidbody>()`